# List all Postgre SQL Databases in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm trying to write a code in C# which lists all the Database in a specific IP Address but I don't know where to start. Please help!!!

Comment: Start by querying the DB metadata. It has the list of all databases. Without seeing your attempt/research; thats about all I can do to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got the answer. I just need to open the postgres database which is created by default when you create a database instance and do this query.

SELECT datname FROM pg_database
WHERE datistemplate = false;

Comment: You don't have to open the postgres database, you can query from any connection. You might also want to add "AND datallowconn = 't'"